# SQLserver hierarchyid data type in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2008-r2, spring-data-jpa, hierarchyid

I am new to SQLserver. I have a table with hierarchyid as the primary key .
When I generated the entity for the table through hibernate reverse engineering the column which had hierarchyid as the datatype has become byte[] in the java entity file.

My question is how do I insert a record for this using spring data JPA and get back the same record.

I have searched for it but with not much success. Your guidance appreciated